# Get duration as timestamp difference for repeated location changes

Tags: mysql

Struggling a little with a SQL query, and would appreciate help to determine the respective duration at the repeatedly changing location for each person.

One table, three columns: **name**, **location** and **timestamp** (new row every two seconds).

```
name location timestamp
fred home     2015-07-08 08:02:15
john home     2015-07-08 08:02:16
fred home     2015-07-08 08:02:17
john home     2015-07-08 08:02:18
fred work     2015-07-08 08:07:30
fred work     2015-07-08 08:07:32
fred work     2015-07-08 08:07:34
john work     2015-07-08 08:09:15
john work     2015-07-08 08:09:17
john work     2015-07-08 08:09:19
fred home     2015-07-08 17:17:35
fred home     2015-07-08 17:17:37
john home     2015-07-08 19:10:15
john home     2015-07-08 19:10:17
john home     2015-07-08 19:10:19
john home     2015-07-08 19:10:21
```

Need to determine how long both fred and john were at home and then at work and then at home again.

Unfortunately although
`TIMEDIFF(min(timestamp), max(timestamp))`
determines the duration, this is an aggregate command. So you have to use `group by name` or `group by location` - after which it aggregates the time into a single duration value (fred was at home between 2015-07-08 08:02:15 and 2015-07-08 17:17:37), which is not correct. He was actually at home between 2015-07-08 08:02:15 and 2015-07-08 08:02:17, and then again later (after being at work for some time) between 2015-07-08 17:17:35 and 2015-07-08 17:17:37.

So I am trying to get the query to show **duration** (in seconds) and '**last seen**':

```
name location duration last_seen
fred home     2        2015-07-08 08:02:17
fred work     4        2015-07-08 08:07:34
fred home     2        2015-07-08 17:17:37
john home     2        2015-07-08 08:02:18
john work     4        2015-07-08 08:09:19
john home     6        2015-07-08 19:10:21
```

Assume I need a query, that determines the duration by person's name until location name changes (then repeat for the next location name change). But time difference as used above always aggregates the data.

Answer (score 0):

Create a view called home_to_work:

```
CREATE VIEW `home_to_work`AS 
    SELECT b.name, NULL AS `home`, b.timestamp AS `work`
    FROM mytable b
    WHERE b.location = 'work'
            AND NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT 1 FROM mytable m
                    WHERE b.name = m.name AND m.timestamp < b.timestamp
     )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.name, a.timestamp AS `home`, b.timestamp AS `work`
    FROM mytable a
    JOIN mytable b
            ON a.name = b.name AND a.location = 'home' AND b.location = 'work'
     AND a.timestamp < b.timestamp
     AND NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT 1 FROM mytable m
                    WHERE a.name = m.name AND m.timestamp > a.timestamp AND m.timestamp < b.timestamp
     )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.name, a.timestamp AS `home`, NULL AS `work`
    FROM mytable a
    WHERE a.location = 'home'
            AND NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT 1 FROM mytable m
                    WHERE a.name = m.name AND m.timestamp > a.timestamp
     );
```

and a view called work_to_home:

```
CREATE VIEW `work_to_home`AS 
    SELECT b.name, NULL AS `work`, b.timestamp AS `home`
    FROM mytable b
    WHERE b.location = 'home'
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM mytable m
            WHERE b.name = m.name AND m.timestamp < b.timestamp
     )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.name, a.timestamp AS `work`, b.timestamp AS `home`
    FROM mytable a
    JOIN mytable b
        ON a.name = b.name AND a.location = 'work' AND b.location = 'home'
     AND a.timestamp < b.timestamp
     AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM mytable m
            WHERE a.name = m.name AND m.timestamp > a.timestamp AND m.timestamp < b.timestamp
     )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.name, a.timestamp AS `work`, NULL AS `home`
    FROM mytable a
    WHERE a.location = 'work'
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM mytable m
            WHERE a.name = m.name AND m.timestamp > a.timestamp
     );
```

then use this query:

```
SELECT `name`, location, `from`, `until`, duration
FROM (
    SELECT h2w.`name`, 'work' AS `location`, h2w.work AS `from`, w2h.work AS `until`, TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, h2w.`work`, w2h.`work`) AS `duration`
    FROM home_to_work h2w
    JOIN work_to_home w2h
      ON h2w.name = w2h.name AND h2w.work < w2h.work AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM mytable m
        WHERE h2w.name = m.name AND m.location = 'home' AND m.timestamp > h2w.work AND m.timestamp < w2h.work
    )

    UNION ALL

    SELECT w2h.`name`, 'home' AS `location`, w2h.home AS `from`, h2w.home AS `until`, TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, w2h.`home`, h2w.`home`) AS `duration`
    FROM work_to_home w2h
    JOIN home_to_work h2w
      ON w2h.name = h2w.name AND w2h.home < h2w.home AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM mytable m
        WHERE w2h.name = m.name AND m.location = 'work' AND m.timestamp > w2h.home AND m.timestamp < h2w.home
    )
) locations
ORDER BY `name`, `from`
```

Explanation: I derive the transitions from home to work, and work to home (including initial null to home/work and final home/work to null) and then join these transitions while checking that they're consecutive.

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2ae5/1).

**Edit in reply to your comment:**

Getting the last known location for a given person and time is easy:

```
SELECT location
FROM mytable
WHERE `name` = 'John' AND timestamp < '2015-07-08 11:07:00'
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Appreciated reaabb but forgot to mention that the ultimate goal is to find the last known location (by time) on particular dates and that the location can also be bank, shop etc. I think the sql (which needs to run concurrently) is getting too complex for me.