# Convert sub queries to joins?

Tags: mysql

After spending some considerable time (thanks Abecee) in creating sub-queries to sort a table I find with dismay that although this works perfectly and rapidly in MySQL Workbench and other tools there are known issues with sub queries when running mysql queries in Java (in a JSP). It is not possible to change my jdbc connect string so I would appreciate any information on whether it is possible to modify the following code to only use joins or something. Note I had to encapsulate the 3 variables in the first SELECT as otherwise mysql in java also throws a syntax error.

I am a SQL newbie so am struggling with this.

```
SELECT @locationID:=0 as LocVar, @ts:=NULL as tsVar, @changed:=0 as changed,
                L4.assetid, L4.node, A.name as Name, L.zonename as Zone, SEC_TO_TIME(duration) as Duration
                FROM 
                (SELECT MIN(assetID) AS assetid, MIN(nodeid) AS node, SUM(secDiff) AS duration, changed
                        FROM
                            (SELECT 
                            assetID
                            , nodeid
                            , @changed := IF(nodeid <> previousLocationID, @changed + 1, @changed) AS changed
                            , IFNULL(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,
                                previousTs,
                                 ts
                                ),
                                0
                                ) AS secDiff
                        FROM
                            (SELECT 
                            assetID
                            , nodeid
                            , @locationID AS previousLocationID
                            , @locationID := nodeid AS currentLocationID
                            , ts
                            , @ts AS previousTs
                            , @ts := ts AS currentTs
                            FROM Logs L1

                        ORDER BY ts
                            ) L2
                        ORDER BY ts
                        ) L3
                        GROUP BY changed
                        ) L4
                        JOIN asset A
                            ON L4.assetid = A.id
                        JOIN node L
                            ON L4.node = L.id
                        where duration != 0
                        ORDER BY changed DESC
```

Thanks.
Active.

Comment: What were you trying to do again?

Comment: Hello Strawberry, this finds total duration (datetime) between table rows up until the nodeid changes and then it repeats for the next nodeid and so on (there can be multiple nodeid's and assetid's in any order and the output must not group by nodeid). The result is then joined with the asset and node tables to provide name and location.  This SQLFiddle ( http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cbb47/1) works perfectly but not when run in a JSP (no output from the query ), various forums indicating that mysql sub-queries have issues in Java.

Comment: Mysql just delivers a resultset. This is a JSP or other Java related issue in using that resultset.

Comment: Yes. agree (and sub-queries mentioned as an issue with mysql calls in Java). Wanted to know whether all the sub-queries could be re-written as joins or is there a better way?

Comment: First a bit of context (having written the original of the above query in [Sum time duration by location change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31441938/sum-time-duration-by-location-change) and the quoted [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cbb47/1)): *The original query uses a MySQL specific technique to compensate for MySQL's lack of `LAG`...* --- Now: In this specific case: I have no idea how to replace the sub-queries by joins, and still have the variables, which in above modification have become part of the `SELECT` clause, doing their job.

Comment: From [Question 31311195](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31311195) it seems, you get a reading every two seconds. Throughout the day? How often do you need to retrieve the result of the [query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cbb47/1)? How current does the result set need to be when checked? (Up to the second, minute, hour, ...?)

Comment: Hello Abecee (thanks for being around at the weekend), there is nothing wrong with your code except that it does not work when run in a JSP (not your fault, Java's fault for not supporting mysql sub-queries properly). Despite the variables now being part of SELECT (to prevent a syntax error) there is no output and no exception thrown by mysql (in jsp).

Comment: On further investigation it is the 3 variables that are causing the issue (in java / jsp). SET causes a SQL error and the variables are being ignored if they are placed inside the first SELECT. This seems to be something peculiar to mysql in java / jsp.

Comment: Once you move them to the select clause, they are no longer variables, and the whole solution approach is overthrown. -- Depending on your overall requirements, and the amount of control you have over the database, a stored routine or an `EVENT` might help you to get, what you need.

Comment: Thanks again, unfortunately all the variables have to be rewritten for Java / jsp (using c:set, c:out etc) and my attempts to do that have failed so far. I have posted this on the Java forum in the hope that someone can help.

Comment: Hello again Abecee, could I ask you to identify (as a list or something) in your code where each variable is only being read or is being written to then read as I have to translate all these into c:out and c:set commands. Thanks. Active.

Comment: @Active Sorry - the SQL statement, I provided earlier, does work as a unit - or not all. There is no passing in and out of variables half way through. - Given, you need to call it from a JSP, my best bet is really, to wrap the whole thing in a MySQL stored routine or a MySQL `EVENT`. -- BTW: To have people, you are addressing, notified of your comments, please, use the *@name* syntax. See [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) for details.

Comment: Thanks again @Abecee, unfortunately I need to pass in other variables from other parameter requests that occur elsewhere in the JSP (including the date range to select etc, which worked well with your mysql code) so a stored procedure etc is just not going to work. After all this (your) effort I am saddened that jstl / jsp is so limited. Asking a non-technical customer to run a raw mysql query to get a basic report is a no-no. Thanks once again. Active.

Comment: @Active You know the details of your overall requirements better than I do... If additional parameters are required, an `EVENT` is likely of limited use. However, if the query is not to be run too frequently: You could first run a stored routine to create a table as output of the query, and then query just this table. Whether you supply a unique name for the table to the routine, or get one back, would be up to you. You'd need to take care of deleting the tables one way or the other.

Comment: Thanks again @Abecee. Unfortunately this has become too technical for me. I looked at some examples of creating and calling stored routines in a jsp (have to use jsp's as this is the web front end to the report) and they were even more horrific than working with variables. I have parked this until I have several months free. Regards. Active.